# Combining YAML Objects via anchors and overriding object values

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to reduce the headache of copying same configuration data (Stored in YAML file) by using anchor tag in YAML. The example YAML looks like :

```yaml
profiles:
  home: &home
    key1: value1
    object1:
      subKey1: subVal1
      subKey2: subVal2
      complexObject:
        something: value
        someOtherThing: value
  
  work: 
    <<: *home
    object1:
      subKey2: completelyDifferentValue # something like this ?!
      complexObject.something: notValue # or something like this ?
```

The equivalent JSON for the above YAML is

```json
{
    "profiles": {
        "home": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "object1": {
                "subKey1": "subVal1",
                "subKey2": "subVal2",
                "complexObject": {
                    "something": "value",
                    "someOtherThing": "value"
                }
            }
        },
        "work": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "object1": {
                "subKey2": "completelyDifferentValue",
                "complexObject.something": "notValue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas what i wanted was :

```json
{
    "profiles": {
        "home": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "object1": {
                "subKey1": "subVal1",
                "subKey2": "subVal2",
                "complexObject": {
                    "something": "value",
                    "someOtherThing": "value"
                }
            }
        },
        "work": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "object1": {
                "subKey1": "subVal1",
                "subKey2": "completelyDifferentValue",
                "complexObject": {
                    "something": "notValue",
                    "someOtherThing": "value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(the additional subKey1 that was removed)
The YAML config file will have Objects inside Objects and idea is to have one parent object and then just copy it and modify a few keys (inside child objects objects)

- I understand that YAML spec might not be very helpful directly in this case and would appreciate any workarounds in python via pyyaml(or some other library) as well!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the bad influence of Java, it is a common misconception that these two YAML structures are equivalent:

```yaml
a.b: c
```

```yaml
a:
  b:
    c
```

They are not. A period in YAML is a content character just like `a`, making the first YAML have a key named `a.b` which does *not* imply a nested mapping.

---

Now about merging: Anchors and aliases exist to be able to serialize arbitrary, possibly cyclic, graphs. Recursive descent (as needed for a deep merge) needs to be wary of such cycles, which is why I assume `<<` is specified not to do this.

What `<<` actually does is that this specific sequence of characters is assigned the tag `!!merge`. The YAML processor then implements merging as „for every mapping that has a key with tag `!!merge`, pull the unknown key-value-pairs from that key's value(s) into the current mapping“.

The problem for you is that while libraries like PyYAML allow you to register custom constructors for user-defined tags, these can only produce a value for the tagged item – however, `!!merge` influences the mapping *around* the tagged value, so its semantics cannot easily reproduced and expanded via custom constructors.

You can, however, simply override PyYAML's merge implementation. For this, inherit from `SafeConstructor`, `FullConstructor` or `UnsafeConstructor` depending on your needs, reimplement [flatten_mapping](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib/yaml/constructor.py#L180), then define a loader ([see here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib/yaml/loader.py)) that uses your constructor. Theoretically, besides deep merging, you can also implement periods-as-nested-mappings here, but I advise against it. These would then only work at places where you do merging, and not elsewhere, which is counter-intuitive.